# My recursive function to search for an element always returns nil

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to implement a recursive function that search for an element into a list.

I have made the following code:

```lisp
(defun encontrar (element lista)
  (if (atom lista)
    (if (eq lista element)
      t
      nil
    )
    (progn
      (loop for element_lista in lista
        do(if (eq (encontrar element element_lista) t)
          t
        )
      )
      nil
    )
  )
)
```

I always get nil as return. I have tryed the following example that should return t:

```lisp
(encontrar #\x '(#\P #\y (#\f \x) #\A))
```

Comment: Note that, if you've been asked to write a recursive function to do this, this is probably not the answer that is being looked for, since you are processing the list iteratively.  The pattern you probably want looks like: 'if it's null, fail, if it's a cons either the first element is what we want or it is one of the remaining elements'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try to find the error.

Since it is a recursive function, `trace`-ing can show us all intermediate steps easily:

```
(trace encontrar)
```

Now, run the same test:

```
(encontrar #\x '(#\P #\y (#\f \x) #\A))

0: (ENCONTRAR #\x (#\P #\y (#\f |x|) #\A))
    1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\P)
    1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
    1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\y)
    1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
    1: (ENCONTRAR #\x (#\f |x|))
      2: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\f)
      2: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
      2: (ENCONTRAR #\x |x|)
      2: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
    1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
    1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\A)
    1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
0: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
```

If you look at the trace, something should be surprising, namely `|x|`. This is a notation for writing symbols literally, without case conversion (which depends on the current readtable; usually symbols are upcased when read), and with characters that should be quoted (like spaces). Here `|x|` is the symbols whose name is the string `"x"` (notice the lowercase). It is not a character, and it is present in your list due to a typo (probably), you wanted to write `#\x` but wrote `\x`, which is another way of quoting symbols.

Let's fix the test:

```
(encontrar #\x '(#\P #\y (#\f #\x) #\A))


0: (ENCONTRAR #\x (#\P #\y (#\f #\x) #\A))
  1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\P)
  1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
  1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\y)
  1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
  1: (ENCONTRAR #\x (#\f #\x))
    2: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\f)
    2: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
    2: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\x)
    2: ENCONTRAR returned T
  1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
  1: (ENCONTRAR #\x #\A)
  1: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
0: ENCONTRAR returned NIL
```

The result is still `NIL`, but notice that the intermediate `(ENCONTRAR #\x #\x)` returns T. Somehow that result is not propagated back up.

Your else case, where the recursive invocation is made, is as follows:

```
(progn
  (loop for element_lista in lista
   do(if (eq (encontrar element element_lista) t)
      t
    )
  )
  nil
)
```

First of all, the formatting is not idiomatic, let's rewrite it:

```
(progn
  (loop
     for element_lista in lista
     do (if (eq (encontrar element element_lista) t)
            t))
  nil)
```

Many things here:

- the expression `(progn e1 .. en)` has for value the one of `en` (this is what the `n` in `progn` means). So here, you have `(progn (loop ...) nil)`, so the first expression's value is discarded and the return value is `nil` (and the loop does not perform jumps)
- `(if test t)` is the same as `(if test t nil)`, which is equivalent to just writing `test` (the returned value might not be literally `t`, but it is non-nil, so in a boolean context it will be interpreted as true.
- likewise, testing `(if (eq test t) t)` is redundant,  because EQ already returns either T or NIL (thanks @Kaz for pointing out mistakes).
- in `(eq lista element)` (base case), `eq` should **not** be used to compare characters in portable programs, as an implementation might return NIL for values that are `char=`. If you want to allow other kind of values than characters, use `eql`, or maybe `equalp` if you don't mind the test to walk the values recursively; but in any case, do not use `eq` because it checks whether two objects are *identical*, but characters (and numbers) that have the same representation might *be* different objects (e.g. bignums).
- the return value of your `loop` is nil, in all cases. What you compute in `do` is discarded because `do` is used for side-effects; if you want to loop until the test is true, use `(loop for x in list thereis (test x))`, or equivalently `(some #'test list)`.

This should help you debug your code.